# what exactly is the syntax error here ? using raw query I want to check email and password exist or not in database

Tags: android, sql, android-studio, android-database

I am checking both the password and email  enter by the user is exist in the database or not

```
String queryEmail="SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + col_2 + " = " +email+ " WHERE " + col_3 + "=" +password;
        Cursor cr=db.rawQuery(queryEmail,null);
        if(cr.moveToFirst())

        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
```

**ERROR:**

```
Process: com.hfad.projectwithsql, PID: 4782
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Employee  WHERE EMPLOYEE_EMAIL = 12 WHERE EMPLOYEE_PASSWORD=1234
```

Comment: I think you forgot to post any useful information

Comment: --->(error occur in this line )String queryEmail="SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + col_2 + " = " +email+ " WHERE " + col_3 + "=" +password;
        Cursor cr=db.rawQuery(queryEmail,null);
        if(cr.moveToFirst())

        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For having multiple conditions in `where` clause you need to use `AND`, replace

```
" WHERE " + col_2 + " = " +email+ " WHERE " + col_3 + "=" +password;
```

With `where col2=email AND col3=password` (with correct formatting of course

here is a link to help you understand better [Multiple Conditions in Where Clause](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/where.php) also explains how to use `AND` & `OR` (multiple conditions in where clause)

Answer (score 0):

You were using WHERE twice, the second WHERE has to be replaced by AND, and also email and password should be passed in single quote. Here is modified code with all suggestions I wrote.

```
String queryEmail="SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + col_2 + " = '" +email+ "' and " + col_3 + "='" +password+'"; 
Cursor cr=db.rawQuery(queryEmail,null); 
if(cr.moveToFirst())
{
  return true;
}else
  return false;
```